# SyntaxError: invalid syntax astype('float32')[:limit] in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code runs in python2, but when I want run it in python3, appears this error :

```py
    images, targets = data
    rng_state = numpy.random.get_state()
    numpy.random.shuffle(images)
    numpy.random.set_state(rng_state)
    numpy.random.shuffle(targets)
    if limit is not None:
        print "WARNING ONLY FIRST {} MNIST DIGITS".format(limit)
        images = images.astype('float32')[:limit]
        targets = targets.astype('int32')[:limit]
    if n_labelled is not None:
        labelled = numpy.zeros(len(images), dtype='int32')
        labelled[:n_labelled] = 1
```

What's then correct syntax in python3?

```
      images = images.astype('float32')[:limit]
             ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `print("WARNING ONLY FIRST {} MNIST DIGITS".format(limit))`

Comment: @CristiFati oh, Thank you, I don't attention it.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, `print` is a function, so you need to wrap its arguments in parentheses:

```
print("WARNING ONLY FIRST {} MNIST DIGITS".format(limit))
```

Comment: Yes, I don't attention it. Thank you :)